# WordPress technical theme design

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In a typical WordPress project I guess there are 3 parties. Party 1 is the graphic designer providing psd/pdf or html that party 2 (the developer) will create a theme from with probably some custom posts so party 3 (the client and content editor) can update the site without messing up the design and with no knowledge about HTML, JavaScript, Gimp or PHP.

This would tie the main theme of the site or it's specific pages in the php page(s) and if some minor design changes need to be made it needs to be done through editing php files.

I was thinking the following for a theme design:

(assuming a content only site without having complicated sales statistics and such)

Instead of "programming" the page.php to fit the graphic design and bring in specific (custom) posts and other data I would have the page.php bring in sub content. This so the graphic designer can create the page without having to program.

When images need to be provided then wordpress can pre scale/crop for different screen sizes.

The entire page should be created from the editor by the designer NOT the editor/client and not in page.php:

```
<html {{lang}}>
  <title>{{title}}</title>
...
{{main-slider}}
```

JS and css are added through custom fields so they can be merged to one file.

Main slider post looks like this:

```
<div id="main-slider">{{main-slider-content}}</div>
```

JS and css can be provided to overrule page css or js and will be merged to one file.

And the `main-slider-content` is content that the editor can provide through a custom post provided by the programmer that will hold the editor's hand all the way and makes sure everything goes right.

Some of these fields can be set with custom fields values of the page (reverting to defaults if missing) some will be overwritten by the post (like language or title).

The type of sites that will be produced by this theme are used by small business owners who would like some web presence.

I have a couple of doubts about the design and hope someone with more experience with wordpress can shed some light on this.

1. When the editor/client edits a custom post like some slider content they cannot preview the item because that content is basically used on every page. Even if I find a way to list pages where the slider is used and show that one it won't show the new content until it's published. Previewing pages seems a bit complicated to implement.
2. It takes longer to generate the pages because content and sub content needs to be fetched from the database after parsing the content. I've tried to do this with DOMDocument before and used `<div data-custom-content="main-slider"></div>` but that is too slow so I'll try with regexp.
3. Because content isn't going to change that much I thought maybe APC cache the page after a first request and serve it from there. Delete the cache only when something is updated. On VPS the cache could be (probably would be) trashed when the site is inactive for a long time (which would be quite often). This means that requests take a long time to process when people try to view the pages.

Anyone with experience or helpful tips in this

**[UPDATE]**

I see that particular design and the html template will still have strong dependencies on each other. I am thinking now of trying out Twig. The benefit will be that re usable components are classes that can be added to the project and full content is controlled in the wordpress editor in a way that someone with no programming experience can still manage the content.

When data needed in the page is going to change a programmer is going to be needed though.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of what the Advanced Custom Fields Flexible Content system does, and the way you've styled your examples looks very like Smarty, a templating system that used to be very popular, and which is still used by a few systems like Prestashop.

In my experience, this removing the middleman kind of idea doesn't work.  You either need a very extensive - and therefore bloated - initial theming system to flex to different projects, or you need a basic one which a developer will customise later - in which case the best you can achieve is moving the developer's role to a different phase of the project.

Overall, I think the best scope for this type of idea is for designers to learn a bit more code.

Comment: Worth noting that this is a kind of discussion-catalysing question, rather than one with a definite answer, so it might be best aimed at a developer forum, rather than StackExchange

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what I am trying to achieve is that content is completely separated from the php logic that fetches the data or filters that need to be applied. While also having parts of the content safely tucked away in custom posts so the client can provide new content without breaking the theme. Thinking of Twig if that can render fast enough. This way instead of copy and pasting functions and html I can copy and paste class files when re using code. The actual html would look simple enough for a non programmer to maintain.

Comment: Having seen code that was produced by designers that learn a bit more code I fear that that solution isn't going to fly. Trying to maintain such a site is in my experience very hard (asp.net sites)